# How to list all directories from other directory with options?

Tags: debian, directory, ls

I would like to list only directories (including hidden) in a given directory (for example `/etc/`) if I'm not in this directory.

If I want to list all directories, including hidden I use the command:

```
ls -d */ .*/
```

I wanted to use this command to list all directories in `/etc`.

```
ls /etc
```

I can do this, but I wanted to combine it with the first one, listing only directories.

```
ls -d */ .*/ /etc
```

or

```
ls /etc -d */ .*/
```

don't work. Why?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because `*/` and `.*/` are not arguments that are passed directly to `ls` - instead, they are globs that are expanded by the shell, giving a list of matching filenames in the current directory that are themselves passed to `ls`

The equivalent for a different directory (`/etc` say) would be

```
ls -d /etc/*/ /etc/.*/
```

If your shell supports brace expansion, you can write that more compactly as

```
ls -d /etc/{,.}*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

Use above command to list only directories including hidden directory being in some other directory